# Can i send data from a form and select drop down to email using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm currently building a form in which a visitor inputs their information and submits it, in then sends an email across to the department that they've selected via the dropdown menu, just wanted to see if this is actually possible and if so how do i continue the IF statement, also is there anything wrong with my code, i'm no pro when it comes to html/php.

```
    <input type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="*Enter Name">

    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="*Enter Email">

    <input type="text" name="company"  placeholder="*Enter Company">
    <br>

    <select id="Visiting">
     <option>Select Department to email</option>
      <option name="Visiting1" value="event1">Operations</option>
      <option name="Visiting2" value="event2">Security</option>
      <option name="Visiting3" value="event3">Shunters</option>  
      <option name="Visiting4" value="event2">Stock & Systems</option>
      <option name="Visiting5" value="event3">Goods In</option>  
      <option name="Visiting6" value="event3">Facilities</option>
      <option name="Visiting7" value="event3">IT</option>
      <option name="Visiting8" value="event3">Despacth</option>
      <option name="Visiting9" value="event3">Transport</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <button type="submit">Sign In</button>

<?php
$name = $_POST['full_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$visitor = $_POST['visitor'];

if($visitor == "security"){
    $mail_to = 'your security email';    
}elseif
  ($visitor == "it"){
    $mail_to = 'your it email';    
}else
  ($visitor == "Transport"){
$mail_to = 'your transport email';




$body_message = 'From: '.$name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$company;
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$visitor;

$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for notifying us, we will be with you shortly.');
    window.location = 'http://nameofwebsite.co.uk';
</script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed. Please, try again or select another department');
    window.location = <'http://nameofwebsite.co.uk.>/';
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is wrong, you can only add a name-attribute to a `<select>`-tag it doesn't work on `<option>`-tags.

Your html code should look like this:

```
<select id="Visiting" name="Visiting">
    <option disabled selected>Select Department to email</option>
    <option value="Visiting1">Operations</option>
    <option value="Visiting2">Security</option>
    <option value="Visiting3">Shunters</option>  
    <option value="Visiting4">Stock & Systems</option>
    <option value="Visiting5">Goods In</option>  
    <option value="Visiting6">Facilities</option>
    <option value="Visiting7">IT</option>
    <option value="Visiting8">Despacth</option>
    <option value="Visiting9">Transport</option>
</select>
```

PHP:

```
$visitor = $_POST['Visiting'];
    switch ($visitor) {
        case 'Visiting1':
        $mail_to = 'your Visiting1email';
        break;
    case 'Visiting2':
        $mail_to = 'your Visiting2 email';
        break;
    case 'Visiting3':
        $mail_to = 'your Visiting3 email';
        break;
    ...
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I will get it checked when i'm back at my desk

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the PHP function `mail()` is probably the issue here if you are getting errors. You must have PHP set up to actually send emails, it doesn't typically work out-of-the-box without some configuration.

SMTP for sending emails is a very old protocol, and in it's original form it didn't require a username/password (authentication) to send an email. It was on the honor system that you weren't spoofing someone else in the "From:" field.

Obviously things have changed, and servers that receive email verify that the origin server matches the "From:" field on the email, and the origin server itself asks for a username/password to be able to send an email in the first place (and restricts the authenticated user's ability to customize the "From:" field as well).

This being said, you can run your own SMTP server and you can do so as insecurely as you like, but other email servers online won't take you very seriously because you'll look like just another spammer out there. Instead it's much more reliable to use an externally "properly" set up SMTP server through a web hosting company, or from a popular web mail service such as Gmail or Yahoo.

Under the hood, PHP's `mail()` function uses the Linux command line utility called `sendmail`. You can also use other libraries out there like PEAR's mail package.

A lot of people have `sendmail` using a default local SMTP server, and set up the that server as a relay to Gmail (or whatever) external server. This way scripts can send emails without a username/password (the relay takes care of that). Obviously this has some security implications, but it can be a simple way to do it.

If you let us know more about what email server you want to send mail from, and what type of server you website is running on, I could point you in the right direction for configuring a mail sending utility.

Comment: Its for a university assignment, basically it would be used on a front reception desk on a tablet so when a visitor comes to the site they sign the form with their name, email and the company they have come from


Then select what department they are visiting, when sending it would ping an email to that email address to let the person know there visitor has arrived, i wouldn't need a smpt server set up just be running on a server we use at university, So i just need it to be able to send successfully, but i fully appreciate how helpful you have been :)